# Fragment overlayed by ViewPager. Cannot go back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager that holds 3 list fragment tabs. When an item is clicked in one of the fragments, a new fragment is replaced on the page I clicked the item. So, the tabs is still visible, but the page is being replaced.

I expected it to replace the whole ViewPager including the tabs. Maybe it's because my layout config isn't properly done.

Anyway, here is the screenshot of the flow I was talking about:

[image: flow]

This is how I get the new fragment called, via an interface:

```
public class UserShopActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        UserItemsFragment.OnUserItemSelectedListener,
        UserSelectedCategoryFragment.OnUserItemsSelectedListener,
        UserCategoriesFragment.OnUserCategoriesSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_shop);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.shop_pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onUserCategoriesSelected(String category_id) {
        UserSelectedCategoryFragment fragment = new UserSelectedCategoryFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("category_id", category_id);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        mViewPager.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.shop_container, fragment)
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

I set the Visibility of the ViewPAger to invisible. My intention is to make it gone rather than overlay the layout. Problem is I don't know how to get it back visible.

`activity_view_shop.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/shop_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/shop_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</FrameLayout>
```

How am I gonna be able to replace the whole ViewPager with a new ListFragment? And when back button (either soft key or back button) is pressed, it goes back to the ViewPager.

If something is missing, please let me know.